# UberSVN on Windows: Take a backup of all repositories at once and restore them

Tags: windows, svn, backup, restore, ubersvn

I am new to SVN and UberSVN on windows. I am using UberSVN 12.04 Free edition (not using any uberapp.)

I would like to know if there is anyway in which I can take the backup of all the repositories at once?
I know that I can take one by one backups for every `Repo`.

Is there any way that I can take backups and restore it at once and it playes well with Uberportal as well. (shows in the repositories tab)

Some detail will be appreciated as I am not to familar with SVN and its configuration.

Comment: Use Windows Server Backup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19720373/761095

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the entire directory if you want to take a cut of your repo's outside of the svn backup options.

There isn't a way to add multiple repo's at once to uberSVN at the moment, you would need to do these individually.

It is something that has been discussed from time to time, but if it's a feature you deem important I'd recommend raising it via the suggestion area [here](http://suggest.ubersvn.com/), then other users can see it and comment etc and we can assess demand.